# Using different metric for hclust linkage?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

In R you can use all sorts of metrics to build a distance matrix prior to clustering, e.g. binary distance, Manhattan distance, etc...
However, when it comes to choosing a linkage method (complete, average, single, etc...), these linkage all use euclidean distance. This does not seem particularly appropriate if you rely on a difference metric to build the distance matrix.

Is there a way (or a library...) to apply other distances to linkage methods when building a clustering tree?

Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You compute the distance matrix with a non-standard distance (I frequently do that e.g. with $\frac{1}{2}(1 - COR (X)$). During the hierarchical clustering *new* distances are computed: the distance of the fused objects (cluster) to all other objects/clusters. The question is: how to make `hclust` use the non-standard distance also for these calculations?

Comment: That would mean that there are (at least) 2 questions in here: a) the programming question. b) the statistics part: is it necessary/good/does it make sense/what is the meaning of using the non-standard distance inside `hclust` given that it operates on the *distance matrix* rather than on the *data matrix*?

Comment: Indeed, this was exactly my question: how to use a non-standard metric in the iterative clustering, i.e. in the linkage method.

Comment: I think here on stackoverflow the programming part of the question can be answered. As I'm more interested in the statistics/maths part of the question, I just posted that part on crossvalidated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35395/hierarchical-cluster-analysis-with-non-standard-distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get your question. For example, suppose I have the following data:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=5)
```

then I can build a distance matrix using `dist`

```
##Changing the distance measure
d_e = dist(x, method="euclidean")
d_m = dist(x, method="maximum")
```

I can then cluster in however I want:

```
##Changing the clustering method
hclust(d_m, method="median")
```

Comment: OK, I guess my question was related to the relation between the metric used to construct the distance matrix and the linkage method selected: is any combination possible, or are certain linkage methods more adapted to certain metrics ? The hclust man page states that _"[...] Dissimilarities between clusters can be efficiently computed (i.e., without ‘hclust’ itself) only for a limited number of distance/linkage combinations, the simplest one being squared Euclidean distance and centroid linkage."_

Comment: If that's your true question (which is a good question!), it's more statistics than computing. Perhaps close (or accept an answer) for this and try in stats.sx

Answer (score 1):

If you have constructed a matrix that already represents the pairwise distances, use e.g.

```
hclust(as.dist(mx), method="single")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using `agnes`, rather than `hclust`, and hand it a distance matrix.  There's a nice tutorial on this here: 
http://strata.uga.edu/software/pdf/clusterTutorial.pdf

From the tutorial, here's how you would generate and use a distance matrix for clustering:

```
> library(vegan)
# load library for distance functions
> mydata.bray <- vegdist(mydata, method="bray")
# calculates bray (=Sørenson) distances among samples
> mydata.bray.agnes <- agnes(mydata.bray)
# run the cluster analysis
```

I myself use Prof. Daniel Müllner's [fastcluster library](http://math.stanford.edu/~muellner/fastcluster.html), which has exactly the same API as `agnes` but is orders of magnitude faster for large data sets.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite see the difference here with the hclust function: hclust also takes as input a distance matrix computed e.g. using the dist or Dist function, and the user can specify a particular linkage method.

Comment: Can you clarify your original question?  I'm confused about what you are asking. Anyway, you can also specify the metric for `agnes` and it will compute the distance matrix for you, although its limited to manhatten and euclidean distances.  In general, I recommend that you just use Prof. Müllner's code, which doesn't have any optimizations for any particular metrics but should outperform both `hclust` and `agnes` anyway.